# Let k is given and numbers from 1 to 100 are written on the board

Tags: combinatorics

Let k is given and numbers from 1 to 100 are written on the board. Ali erases from the board arbitrary k numbers. Is it true that Bob may choose k numbers written on the board, which sum is equal to 100. Consider cases when a) k = 8, b) k = 9

Comment: Erase numbers 1-9, and you can't get 100 from exactly 9 of the remaining numbers. Did you mean to say Bob can choose any amount of numbers?

Comment: @Abuyazan Whenever you ask a question, you should add what you have tried, what are your difficulties... It helps people who are answering to understand your problem and shows that you at least tried to solve it.

Comment: Did you mean to say Bob can choose any amount of numbers? k numbers  a) k=8 , b) k=9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $k = 8$ it is always possible. To see why, you can analyze in how many ways you can write $25$ as a sum of two distinct numbers. Notice that there are $12$ pairs that sum $25$, namely $(1, 24), (2, 23), \ldots, (12, 13)$. When Ali eliminates $8$ numbers, he destroys at most $8$ of these pairs. Notice that for any choice, there must remain at least $4$ of these pairs. Then, Bob can simply pick these $8$ numbers.

For $k = 9$, if Ali picks the numbers, from $1$ to $9$ then the minimum sum that Bob can make is $10 + 11 + \ldots + 18 = 126 > 100$.

Comment: Thanks Daniel , got the idea